# Automatic Redirection? Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

how can I make a  landing site that auto-redirects a user login to their specific client site? based on data from a list. 
I have created a list with users and their websites

Comment: You can create a sitepage, Set that page as welcome page(landing page), add a custom webpart to that page.
Within the webpart write the redirection logic

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create one page in a pages library or SitePages library,
2. Make that page as a welcome page
3. Create one custom web part which ahs a logic to read current user details and a logic to read data from the list.
4. Drop  that web part in a page automatically by code
5. Write a logic to redirect a user to their particular sites

Hope this helps